# Django checking if model fields are equal

Tags: django, compare, field, models

So I got this

```
{% if articulo.Tipos == sth.tipo %}
    Equal
{% else %}
    Not Equal
{% endif %}
```

But even if the fields have the same value, it doesnt return true.
By the way, articulo.Tipo is the foreign key of sth.tipo , any idea why isnt it working properly ?

Models:

```
class Productos(models.Model):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey("TiposOpciones", null=True, blank=True, related_name='Productos_tipo')

class TiposOpciones(models.Model):
    Tipos = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Views:

```
tiposopciones = TiposOpciones.objects.all()
productos = Productos.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **ifequal**

```
{% ifequal articulo.Tipos sth.tipo|slugify %}
    Equal
{% else %}
    Not Equal
{% endifequal %}
```

also i would suggest checking the datatypes of both!

EDIT:

you can coerce a str to an int using the add filter

```
{% for item in numItems|add:"0" %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add

to coerce int to str just use slugify

```
{{ some_int|slugify }}
```

Comment: If equal doesnt work either, sth.tipo is a foreignkey field and articulo.Tipos is a char field

Comment: ah! there you go. you are comparing an integer with character. Try to cast it in your view

Comment: Sorry , but i didnt get how could I compare if they where storing the same value :S

Comment: I mean how can I use the slugify inside the if ?

Comment: try this: {% ifequal articulo.Tipos sth.tipo|slugify %}

Answer (score 1):

To debug such cases it's handy to display the values you compare in template:

```
articulo.Tipos = '{{ articulo.Tipos }}'<br>
sth.tipo = '{{ sth.tipo }}'<br>

{% if articulo.Tipos == sth.tipo %}
    Equal
{% else %}
    Not Equal
{% endif %}
```

Also, if you compare instances, it's good idea to compare *their IDs*:

```
{% if articulo.Tipos.id == sth.tipo.id %}
```

Comment: When comparing model instances Django does automatically compare the IDs behind the scenes.

Comment: I dont want to check for id , but for values. Also seems like articulos.Tipos.id doesnt return anything because its a foreign key i suppose ? Any other idea to check for the values ?

Comment: If you'll add your models code to your question, it will help.

Comment: OK, now tell, which model you have put into ```articulo``` and ```sth``` template variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do

```
{% if articulo.id == sth.tipo.id %}
   Equal
{% else %}
   Not Equal
{% endif %}
```

sth.tipo is actually an object and your are comparing character with object.The reason you saw same value in admin panel is because in your TiposOpciones model you have used

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.Tipos
```

this returns Tipos string value but actually sth.tipo is object. Try printing the tipo value in console then it will show something like

```
Productous Object(id)
```

which is object so in your case character(Tipos) is being compared with object(tipos) of TiposOpciones.You would want to compare it with id because its a primary key once you have primary key you can garb any other field value for that instance